# ReactJS is there a way to get all parent context providers

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-component

Is it possible to get all parent context providers?

```
<Context1.Provider value={...}>
<Context2.Provider value={...}>
<div>
...
<ContextNotIncluded.Provider value={...}>...</ContextNotIncluded.Provider>
<ContextN.Provider value={...}>
<Component />
</ContextN.Provider>
...
</div>
</Context2.Provider>
</Context1.Provider>
```

is there a way to get all **parent** Context providers as list inside `Component`? Like
`Context1, Context2, ContextN`, without `ContextNotIncluded`, as it is not a parent of `Component`.